# Dealing in Interest while Living in a Non-Muslim Country

Tags: practical-islam, hanafi, finance, banking

If a person lives in a country which has an interest based banking system then is he not allowed to work in any company or institution then? As all companies will comply with the government rules including the ones on interest. Also I heard that Imam Abu Hanifa had said that if you are living in a Non-Muslim Country then you can work in a interest driven market. He said this when Muslims were going to Europe to spread Islam and had to work in the interest based market of Christian Europe. Is this is true then please provide the citations for this.

Comment: Abu Hanifa considered taking interest from a Harbi Kafir to be permitted, as taking their wealth is in general permitted as it is not sacred. The exception is that when a Muslim enters their territory with 'aman' he\she can not take their wealth in any way which involves deception but should be with their consent.

Comment: @UmH ok can you provide the relevant source for this statement

Comment: It may be found in books of fiqh under the relevant topics, for example in [الهداية](https://al-maktaba.org/book/11820/632#p8).

Comment: Note that the majority takes the stance contrary to Imam Abu Hanifa in this matter. Also your question IMO is somewhat tangential to this.

Comment: @UmH please provide the source for this claim as well

Comment: @UmH Thanks I'll check

Comment: Being honest one can hardly avoid dealing with interest even in Muslim countries. The point is what to do with this riba-money? As for Muslim residents in non-Muslim countries many modern scholars relaxed the ruling on some transactions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

السلام عليكم و رحمة الله،

(ٱلَّذِینَ یَأۡكُلُونَ ٱلرِّبَوٰا۟ لَا یَقُومُونَ إِلَّا كَمَا یَقُومُ ٱلَّذِی یَتَخَبَّطُهُ ٱلشَّیۡطَـٰنُ مِنَ ٱلۡمَسِّۚ ذَ ٰ⁠لِكَ بِأَنَّهُمۡ قَالُوۤا۟ إِنَّمَا ٱلۡبَیۡعُ مِثۡلُ ٱلرِّبَوٰا۟ۗ وَأَحَلَّ ٱللَّهُ ٱلۡبَیۡعَ وَحَرَّمَ ٱلرِّبَوٰا۟ۚ فَمَن جَاۤءَهُۥ مَوۡعِظَةࣱ مِّن رَّبِّهِۦ فَٱنتَهَىٰ فَلَهُۥ مَا سَلَفَ وَأَمۡرُهُۥۤ إِلَى ٱللَّهِۖ وَمَنۡ عَادَ فَأُو۟لَـٰۤىِٕكَ أَصۡحَـٰبُ ٱلنَّارِۖ هُمۡ فِیهَا خَـٰلِدُونَ)
[سورة البقرة 275]

Any transaction with interest is haram.

This is a limitation set by god, not mere humans, any person who says otherwise is talking outside of the boundaries of Islam, no matter what his "status" may be to a subpart of Muslims.

The fact your company/boss is not applying the laws of shariaa doesn't make you responsible for his acts, the same way you're not responsible for him not being a muslim for instance.
In the end you are paid for providing services, the provenance of the money he's paying you with is outside of your reach, and the way the state you live in is handling your taxes is also outside of your reach.

You're only judged upon what you can act on, in this case what you've done with the money you've been paid for.
Allah will never make you take a burden that you can't handle.

Furthermore, with this reasoning of yours, you could just as well cut yourself from the whole world because pretty much all countries are involved in world wide commerce which implies some kind of interest. So you wouldn't be buying anything from anyone because you would be supporting the global world system which is anti-islamic, and this is a direct non-sense.

Allah is the Owner of Everything, and he is the Only One that distributes the wealth on earth.

Humble Regards

Comment: Thanks a lot. I totally agree with you but I have heard this same reasoning from (the one I gave in the question) a lot of sources but didn't quite believe them but still wanted to confirm to be absolutely sure.